# Make an "either... or... " distinction for install_requires in setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py

If designing a setup.py and there are requirements that can be fulfilled through two different modules, i.e. only one of the two needs to be installed, how do I express that in the `install_requires` line?
E.g. the `setup.py` looks like this:

```
setup(
    name='my_module',
    version='0.1.2',
    url='...',

    ...,

    install_requires=['numpy', 'tensorflow']
)
```

When doing `pip install my_module` this will install **tensorflow** (CPU) as a requirement, even though **tensorflow-gpu** is installed (which would meet the requirement as well, but doesn't, since it's named differently).

Can I do something like:

```
    install_requires=['numpy', 'tensorflow' or 'tensorflow-gpu']
```

Answer (score 7):

The `setup.py` is just another python script, so you can put any logic in it to determine the correct setup args. For example, you can check whether `tensorflow` or `tensorflow_gpu` are installed and modify the list of install deps on the fly:

```
from pkg_resources import DistributionNotFound, get_distribution
from setuptools import setup


def get_dist(pkgname):
    try:
        return get_distribution(pkgname)
    except DistributionNotFound:
        return None


install_deps = []

if get_dist('tensorflow') is None and get_dist('tensorflow_gpu') is None:
    install_deps.append('tensorflow')


setup(
    ...
    install_requires=install_deps,
)
```

Note, however, that once you start putting code in your setup script that performs any stuff at *install* time, you can't distribute wheels anymore because wheels don't ship the `setup.py`, instead executing them once at *build* time. Source distributions will serve just fine:

```
$ python setup.py sdist
running sdist
running egg_info
...
creating dist
Creating tar archive
removing 'mypkg-0.0.0' (and everything under it)
```

Installing the resulting source tar will pull `tensorflow` if not installed:

```
$ pip install dist/mypkg-0.0.0.tar.gz
Processing ./dist/mypkg-0.0.0.tar.gz
Collecting tensorflow (from mypkg==0.0.0)
...
Installing collected packages: tensorflow, mypkg
Successfully installed mypkg-0.0.0 tensorflow-1.6.0
```

Answer (score 6):

You need an `extras_require` in your setup function:

```
extras_require = {
    'gpu':  ['tensorflow-gpu'],
    'cpu': ['tensorflow']
},
```

Which then can be installed with:

`pip install your_package[gpu]` or `pip install your_package[cpu]`

[Source](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies)